# how do i remove value from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

i need help in this:i want to remove from a string a specific value.
for example 
i have this code:

```
document.getElementById("sub_subject_temp"+id1).value = old_sub_subject_string.replace(/theVal/,"");
```

if my string is:

```
6-7,6-3,6-1,
```

and i want to remove:

```
6-3,
```

it would look like this: 6-7,6-1,
i have tryed the

```
str.replace(/val/, "");
```

but it return 6,
any idea to do this thing?

Answer (score 2):

```
"6-7,6-3,6-1".replace(/6-3,/, '');

//"6-7,6-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the string you want to remove, not `"val"`? Try

```
str.replace(/6-3,/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you use a variable `val` whose value is like `6-3;`, you need to use `new RegExp()` to construct the regex.

```
var str = '6-7,6-3,6-1,';
var val = '6-3,';
str = str.replace(new RegExp(val), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without `.replace`. Although it is more complex, it works.

```
var rstring = "6-7,6-3,6-1";
var nstring = rstring.split("6-3,");
var finishedstr = nstring[0] + nstring[1];
```

So, in the above code the original string is split into two while removing `"6-3,"` from the string. The two new sub-strings are recombined without the `"6-3,"`, allowing a finished string of `"6-7,6-1"`, or in this case, the variable `finishedstr`.

Comment: Hope this helps! If anybody has questions, feel free to comment them.